# What computer has the longest uptime?

Tags: history

Inspired by a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H62hZJVqs2o) I saw recently that claims a very high uptime for the computers on the Voyager probes, I was curious -- what computer currently has the longest continuous runtime?

For the purposes of this question, let's define "computer" as a stored program digital electronic computer.

Comment: Given the possibility of the answer being a satellite, I worry that the answer is going to be something confusing to do with relativity. Helios-B seems to have made it to 0.02% the speed of light, if that helps anybody.

Comment: @Tommy: time passes slower at those speeds, I believe.

Comment: Space hardware often resets and goes into a safe mode. At least a soft reset if not a hard reset of almost all systems and a slow boot/recovery process to get everything working again.

Comment: @Tommy Time dilation on a human scale doesn't really become a significant factor until you approach quite close to c, 80% or higher.  A spacecraft travelling away from Earth for a million years in Earth's frame at 0.02% c will have a clock just over a week slower than on Earth at the end.

Comment: If “uptime” is defined as cpu above 90% utilization then we used to run our unix machines running cfd for 40 days continuous to solution...

Comment: Not really about "longest", but there are some fun stories in the comments: https://hardware.slashdot.org/story/13/03/14/2029205/solaris-machine-shut-down-after-3737-days-of-uptime

Comment: +1 Great youtube link ... as mentioned in other comments critical systems use **Watchdog** which is HW invoked interrupt (with some frequency) that resets the control system occasionally to prevent/recover from control system freeze so Up time got reseted too ...

Comment: At least it’s reassuring to know that my estimation of how well I understand relativity isn’t too far off.

Comment: @SolarMike Uptime doesn't have anything to do with 90% CPU usage, and very few computers would attain that over the kinds of periods of interest here. I have personally known several different systems that attained uptime of over a year, which I don't think is in any way exceptional, and those systems would have been completely idle at least 65% of the time.

Comment: @user207421 re-read what I said "**if uptime is defined as...**" but it does not **have** to be...

Comment: @SolarMike I know what you said. I don't understand why you would even consider such a strange definition.

Comment: @user207421 because using the machine is what it is designed for...

Comment: @SolarMike I'm using my computer for what it is designed for but CPU utilisation is running at about 4%. It's definitely up though and `uptime` reports over 33 days.

Comment: Staying up and running while doing little is not much of a test, unless perhaps you're testing power supplies :-)

Comment: I've never heard of uptime being dependent on CPU utilization as @SolarMike suggests, but in either case, I routinely have servers in an HPC environment running at 100% utilization across 36+ physical cores for 12+ weeks at a time (for a single job and I don't reboot between jobs) and I have also had a much older system (Ultrix) up for almost 1000 days before it lost power and rebooted.

Answer (score 11):

The question is tricky in a fundamental way.

> [...] very high uptime [...] longest continuous runtime

**One part** lies in the definition of these, partly contradicting, terms as well in what the computer is. Uptime is a term used for high level operating systems - such as a Unix system - but the Voyager systems are embedded computers running their application on bare metal. So the basic definition for uptime is already hard to tie to a core component.

Embedded systems are quite different from general purpose systems by being almost entirely interrupt-driven. One feature of embedded systems is that they routinely restart - restart being in fact the most important non-maskable interrupt. All to increase stability. So of course, some 'working since installed' time can be counted (*1), but it is rather meaningless in sense of computing value, as the systems aren't really running continuously.

Even by settling on some hypothetical overall working time, the result is still a rather meaningless value. After all, any such number would only be useful to compare *comparable* systems - and the Voyager computers are in no way comparable to any non-embedded systems in operation.

**The other part** is within the meaning of "uptime" itself. It can be given for various components with different meaning. It could define how long a system has been continuously powered. Or how long an OS has been running unstopped on a machine, or how long an application has run unstopped.

Think for example about an x86 machine running Linux running some large scale application like a database server - or better, a MUD. To a hardware person, the power up time is all that counts, while players would only look at the duration their game world persists. Fun part: neither cares about the OS-uptime. In fact, not even the admin does, as his job is to provide a running MUD, not just hardware or an OS.

The single case that the OS-uptime would matter is only true in a situation where the OS itself is the service provided - to many independent users. Not often nowadays, where everyone got has their own machine using services on remote servers - making one of our most favoured benchmark values rather useless to real life :))

**Bottom line:** *The question sounds cool, but doesn't work out in this case.*

---

Now, if we accept all of this and just settle for some 'working since installed' time, the best candidates might well be some traffic light systems of the early 1970s. :)

---

*1 - Well, and then it can't, as probe systems are usually don't work full-time, but go into sleep mode as often as possible to save on power.

Comment: Naa, they go down. Especially in the old days systems had daily downtimes for backup and disk reorganization. More important, these systems have been replaced with new hardware and extended software dozends of times since the 1970s. So while the core software may still have the same structure, it hasn't been running couninous in any definable way.

Comment: Embedded systems don't work that way, at least not most of them.

Comment: Even with non embedded systems, uptime means different things to different people. There are mainframes that allegedly have uptimes measured in months or years but I think that usually refers to the operating system: in such cases they might still take the application off line for backups etc. My first paid work was on a system running on Unisys large computer architecture. Theoretically, it could run forever - even backups were done on line, but the application was so buggy, if it went a week without crashing we were doing well.

Comment: @JeremyP I don't see any confusion... the question asks about _computer up-time_, so applications crashing (or even being started / stopped in a controlled manner) etc. have nothing to do with it. So long as the machine / operating system is still going (and hasn't been rebooted), that's one span of up-time.

Comment: @Raffzahn I was intending to refer to only non-embedded systems (the comment I was responding to starts "_Even with non embedded systems..._"). Should have made that clearer.

Comment: @TripeHound Ah, ok - comment deleted. But even then uptime is still a vague concept, as it may refer to applications as well. After all, the OS on its own is rather meaningless, isn't it?